# Alternatives to adding an @link blade directive for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm considering adding an `@link` blade directive. Something like `@link($user)` and convert that to `<a href="/user/$user->id">$user->name</a>`.

I can, over time make it more complicated, where the link depends on the Type of `$user`, like `$order`, etc. I can add methods to the object, like getHref, and getLinkName.

It seems like a good and simple idea, but I don't see anyone else doing this pattern online.

I'm aware of a few alternative ways to express the same, for example {{$user->makeLink()}}, {{$linkMaker->link($user}}, link_to_*

My question is, has this been done before? Is there a package that uses blade directives to generate a link?

If it hasn't been done before, is there a reason to avoid it? For example, in 5.1 the documentation has removed Blade::extends. Or, its a bad idea to have blade templates generate HTML, it was designed to output string.

The code below works - my question is should I be using someone else's package, or a different pattern.

```
    \Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler) {
        $pattern = "/(?<!\w)(\s*)@link\(\s*(.*?)\)/";
        return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<a href="/user-management/view/<?php echo $2->getRouteKey() ?>"><?php echo $2->name ?></a>', $view);
    });
```

Comment: Yep, here is a package which provide you with functions like `link_to`, `link_to_route`, etc. https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html . It was a part of Laravel, but had been removed since `5.*`. Here is the documentation for it http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls. And I like your idea about wrap it to a blade directive. Lately I'm thinking about the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Blade::extend` for this as described in [Blade Extensions in Laravel](http://blog.zerilliworks.net/blog/2013/04/03/blade-extensions-in-laravel/#markup-extensions) and [Blade Extensions in Laravel 4](http://blog.zerilliworks.net/blog/2013/07/10/blade-extensions-in-laravel-4/) in your case you can create code similar to following:

```
Blade::extend(function ($view, $compiler) {
    $pattern = '/\s*@userlink\(\s*([0-9]*)\s*\)/';
    preg_match($pattern, $view, $matches);
    $userId = $matches[1];
    $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
    return '<a href="/user/'.$user->id.'">'.$user->name.'</a>';
});
```

Place above code in a file, such as `app/blades.php` and require them in your environment file (i.e., `app/start/local.php`). If you haven't specified environments, put them in `app/start/global.php`. Like

```
require app_path()."/blades.php";
```

at the bottom of the file.

and then you can use following in your blade template to use this new blade command

```
@userlink(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `illuminate\html` package has helper functions for generating links (`link_to()`, `link_to_asset()`, `link_to_route()`, `link_to_action()`). The documentation for these helpers can still be found in the Laravel 4 docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls).

This package was removed from Laravel 5, but it can be added back in with no problems.

So, instead of `@link($user)`, your blade syntax would be `{!! link_to_route('user.show', $user->name, [$user->id]) !!}`

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer the more verbose {!! link_to_route('user.show', $user->name, [$user->id]) !!} to @link($user)

Comment: @mrwaim Just that it already exists. I wasn't saying it was better, just letting you know it was out there.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason to not use blade templates, is that it is difficult to handle parenthesis.

@link($reportManager->getBestUser()) failed to parse. You could fix the regex, but that could make things worse.

The second reason, is having implemented `@link`, the complication that comes with it is the requirement to output a PHP snippet, and not a simple HTML or closure.

Outputing a PHP snippet is harder to expand.

For example, to add a condition, if the user is an admin, or the user themselves, or if they report to the user, they see a link, else they see just the name.

Here is what it looks like

```
\Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler) {
    $pattern = "/(?<!\w)(\s*)@link\(\s*(.*?)\)/";
    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1'
        . '<?php if($auth->admin || $auth->id == $2->id || $auth->id == $2->referral_id) {?>' . PHP_EOL
        . '<a href="/user-management/view/<?php echo $2->getRouteKey() ?>">' . PHP_EOL
        . '<?php echo $2->name ?>' . PHP_EOL
        . '</a>' . PHP_EOL
        . '<?php } else { ?>' . PHP_EOL
        . '<?php echo $2->name ?>' . PHP_EOL
        . '<?php }?>', $view);
});
```

Its not pretty, and hard to expand further.

The "logical" next step is then have @link convert to

However, make_link has been coded up and registered, then the value of {!! make_link($user) !!} versus @link($user) is marginal.

The code above, is fairly specific - but the general idea is that blade extensions work best for small and simple HTML transformations, and for anything more complicated, it becomes difficult.